# Calculating resistor values for an amplifier

Tags: transistors, resistors, bias

[image]

How do we calculate the value of the resistors Rb and Re? The information given are limited:

(β = 600)

Ic = 10mA.

It is always preferred to have a symmetrical output voltage swing.

Comment: if beta === 600, then you can calculate values. In practice, that never happens, which is why this circuit is not used. Replace rb with a potential divider to set the base voltage, run 10x the expected base current through the divider. This swamps the variations when beta changes by a factor of 2 or more in either direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Let Ve= Vce/2 = 5V with a ~9Vpp swing possible thus Re=5/10m= 0.5k=**500 Ω**
- As a check, the emitter resistor must always be less than the AC load path R used as an output,

  - which for 10mA, satisfies this requirement of 500 < (100+2200)
  - This is the same as saying the DC bias current must always be greater than the peak AC load current.
    .
- there are several approaches to solve this if we let Rb=hFe*Re for DC bias this

  - when Rb matches the input DC impedance = " Rinput "= hFE*Re , we have a 50% voltage divider, thus Rb=600*500=**300 kΩ** as a crude estimate.
- but for Ib=Ic/hFE = 10mA/600 = 16.7 uA, we expect Vbe=0.65V

  - Vbe vs Ib depends on the I max current ratings and thus bulk chip size
  - But we know this Vb must be Vbe drop plus Ve=5V so make an assumption
  - **let Rb = V(Rb)/(Ib=Ic/hFE)** = ((10V - 5V - 0.65) / 10mA) * 600
  - Rb = 4.35/10mA *600 = **261 kΩ**   or just slightly below the previous estimate
- with test validation, you should expect a 9Vpp swing possible.
- keep in mind the operating point is directly proportional to hFE tolerance

Comment: .. i don't understand how did we have Ve= Vce/5 ... in the first place?

Comment: we didn't.  I chose Ve=5V then determined Rb/Re= hFE then later using Vbe offset

Answer (score 0):

For a symmetric output swing, with a 10V supply, Ve must be what?

Then Ic is 10mA and beta is large so Ie approximately equals Ic, therefore from ohms law Re = Ve/Ie gives what?

Ib = Ie/beta and Vbe is about 0.7V for a silicon transistor, so Vb = Ve + 0.7V. Voltage across Rb = 10 - Vb, and we know Ib so ohms law easily finds Rb.

It is but the way a really poor amplifier as the bias strongly depends on beta and that is very poorly defined in a BJT.