# Common collector amplifier current amplification

Tags: transistors, current, amplifier, common-collector

given:

```
  Re = 500 Ω
  Rb = 261 kΩ
```

[image]

What can we tell about the **current amplification**? Is this circuit useful?

Comment: Well, this is a follower *(i.e. provides a high impedance input and low impedance output with a gain of 0.99999)* and makes it possible for the load to draw more current. For current amplification, if you look at carefully, you can see that input impedance is a few hundreds of \$k\Omega\$ and output impedance is \$100 \Omega\$. So we can say that this circuit has a lot of current gain. But \$R_e\$ seems to small --this may lead to clipping on the output stage.

Comment: If the circuit works well, you can make conclusions about the transistor's current gain. If you know the current gain, you can make conclusions about how well (or otherwise) the circuit will work. Then, knowing the spread of current gains for your chosen transistor will tell you how useful (or otherwise) the circuit is, and what you might need to fix. This looks like a duplicate of http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/262646/amplifying-current-using-a-buffer and http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/261142/calculating-resistor-values-for-an-amplifier

Comment: I'd say - without knowing the gain of the transistor you have no way of knowing what the voltage is across Re (500R). Working backwards a voltage of  5V at the emitter (10mA emitter, 16.9uA base) would require a current gain of about 590 (16.9uA base)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the circuit is not that useful. What most folk would aim for is the emitter dc voltage to be about 50% of the supply rail so that any signal can swing equally positive and negative without asymmetrically clipping.

The dc voltage on the base therefore needs to be set at half rail plus 0.7 volts. It's an emitter follower and this means emitter "follows" the base voltage for dc and most ac conditions. To this end add a resistor from base to 0 volts.

So now, with proper biasing of the base voltage, you can lower the bias resistor values so that you are not overly relying on the native current gain of the transistor. Start thinking about bias resistor values that take through them about one-tenth of the dc emitter current.

Also, I would urge you to use a sim tool like LTSpice.

Comment: You are quite right! The design of that circuit is totally wrong, base bias is impredictable. But I'd rather think using Spice is not a good idea for the OP. Generally unless you know very well what you are feeding to symulator you just get garbage out of it. In this case determistic beta of BJT model would let him think that's a good circuit.

Comment: @carloc this is just a basic amplifier from our first lecture of amplifiers, now we are looking at the improved versions! :D